# slow mp4 video in chrome and node-webkit

Tags: performance, google-chrome, video

I'm making an app in node-webkit which plays an already downloaded (so local) mp4 video (1080p). I copied the ffmpegsumo.dll from my chrome installation, and it does play. But it is very slow (cpu is around 99%).

I would assume this is a hardware issue, but when I play the video in windows media player on the same system, it runs fine (cpu around 25%).

I tried to run the video in basic chrome (as opposed to node-webkit) and I get the same results (way too high cpu-load). I checked the settings in about:flags and everything seems normal (all accelerations are turned on).

So how can this difference exist? And better yet, how can I make the video play with the same speed in chrome as in windows media player?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running on (Win/Mac/Linux)?